# Variable's value doesn't change in remote process

Tags: java, android, process

So, I have an activity and a service. Service's doing a lot of work that hangs my main application's thread, so I decided to run this service in a remote process (:remote in Manifest). Though everything was working while the service was working in the main process, in the remote process something odd happens.

On the end of onCreate method in my service I set SERVICE_RUNNING variable's value to *true*. Log.d one line above confirms, that its value really is *true*. But when I call the static method isRunning() (which returns SERVICE_RUNTIME's value) from my activity, it returns false. Here's my code:

Service:

```
public class PlayService extends Service {
    private static Boolean RUNNING = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SERVICE_RUNNING = true;
        Log.d("ctw", "onCreate() " + SERVICE_RUNNING); // "onCreate() true" in logcat
    }

    public static Boolean isRunning()
    {
        Log.d("ctw", "isRunning() " + SERVICE_RUNNING);
        return SERVICE_RUNNING;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
if(PlayService.isRunning())
{
    // executes when service is running and PlayService is not a remote process
} else {
    // executes always when PlayService is a remote process
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you have separate processes. So each process has it's own PlayService class loaded and own instance of RUNNING flag. You cant share data via static vars between different processes.

Run service in separate thread, not process.

If you are really want different processes than use AIDL to communicate with service.

Comment: Well, so I'll just use AsyncTask in the PlayService class. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You also can use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which handles all requests consequently on a single worker thread